# Different Colored Markers with JvectorMaps

Tags: jquery, html, jvectormap

With JVectorMap, How can I add two sets of markers that are different colors? There's been one other question asked about it and the solution didn't work on JSFiddle. Right now I have markers like and I can attribute types, but I don't know the code that would change the colors of specific types. Any help?

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#map').vectorMap({
    map: 'us_aea_en',
    zoomOnScroll: true,
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    markerStyle: {
      initial: {
        fill: '#800000',
        stroke: '#383f47'
      }
    },
    markers: [
      {latLng: [41.50, -87.37], name: 'Test1 - 2010', type : "chicago"},
      {latLng: [39.16, -84.46], name: 'Test2 - 2010'},
      {latLng: [39.25, -84.46], name: 'Test3 - 2010'}
    ] 


    });
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 13):

In the documentation of the plugin it is said:

> Each marker is represented by latLng (array of two numeric values),
>   name (string which will be show on marker's tip) **and any marker
>   styles**.

So what we do is the following.

```
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
    markers: [
        { latLng: [38.90, -98.45], name: 'John Doe', style: {r: 8, fill:'yellow'}},
        { latLng: [46.90, -65], name: 'Label name', style: {r: 12, fill:'black'}},
        { latLng: [46.90, -65], name: 'Label name', style: {r: 4, fill:'red'}}
    ]
});
```

This way for every marker you create there will be different styles assigned to it.

Answer (score 12):

You may use style for different colors:

```
{latLng: [41.50, -87.37], name: 'Test1 - 2010', style: {fill: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.1)', r:20}},
```

Answer (score -1):

try scales:

```
    markers: [
       {latLng: [41.50, -87.37], name: 'Test1 - 2010', type : "chicago"},
       {latLng: [39.16, -84.46], name: 'Test2 - 2010'},
       {latLng: [39.25, -84.46], name: 'Test3 - 2010'}
    ],
    scales: {
        markers:[{
           attributes: 'fill',
           scale: ['#000000/*color1*/', '/*color2*/'....],
           values: [0, 1, 2]
       }]
    }
```