# different style for different ports in vector map

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

Hi guys this is my JavaScript code to make ip marker for vector map to show online ip..

all ips have 3 different port like:   ip1:1020 or ip2:5050 or ip3:6969

the format for my ips that i can read from ip.txt file like is :

```
{"relays":[{
"or_addresses":["2.176.82.122:1020"],"latitude":35.6961059570313,"longitude":51.423095703125},
{"or_addresses":["2.177.37.250:5050"],"latitude":35.6961059570313,"longitude":51.423095703125},
{"or_addresses":["2.178.57.250:6969"],"latitude":35.6961059570313,"longitude":51.423095703125},
{"or_addresses":["2.18.5.20:5050"],"latitude":35.6961059570313,"longitude":51.423095703125},
{"or_addresses":["2.78.7.25:1020"],"latitude":35.6961059570313,"longitude":51.423095703125}
]}
```

and this is my main script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#worldmap').vectorMap({
map: 'world_mill_en',
scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
hoverOpacity: 0.7,
hoverColor: false,
markerStyle: {
  initial: {
    fill: '#cc6600',
    stroke: '#222222',
    r: 2
  }
},
backgroundColor: '#CCC',
markers: [
]
});

map = $('#worldmap').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1/bantools/ip/ip.txt', function(data){
$.each(data.relays, function(idx, relay)
    {
        map.addMarker(relay.or_addresses[0], {'latLng' : [relay.latitude, relay.longitude], "name" : relay.or_addresses[0]});
    });
});
});
</script>
```

my question is how i can make different style for different PORTS ????! 
my means i want to use this style for port = 1020 :

```
markerStyle: {
  initial: {
    fill: '#cc6600',
    stroke: '#222222',
    r: 2
  }
}
```

and for port = 5050 i want to use this style :

```
markerStyle: {
  initial: {
    fill: '#aaa',
    stroke: '#bbb',
    r: 2
  }
}
```

and for other port...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different Colored Markers with JvectorMaps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922679/different-colored-markers-with-jvectormaps)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsbin.com/womoqa/edit?js,output

```js
$(function(){
  $('#world-map-markers').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    hoverOpacity: 0.7,
    hoverColor: false,
    backgroundColor: '#383f47',
    markers: [
      {latLng: [41.90, 12.45], name: 'Vatican City', 
       style: {
         fill: '#cc6600',
         stroke: '#222222',
         r: 5
       }},
      {latLng: [17.11, -61.85], name: 'Antigua and Barbuda',
       style: {
         fill: '#ff0000',
         stroke: '#222222',
         r: 8
       }},
      {latLng: [0.33, 6.73], name: 'São Tomé and Príncipe',
       style:{
        fill: '#F8E23B',
        stroke: '#383f47'
      }}
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://jvectormap.com/js/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jvectormap.com/js/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jvectormap.com/css/jquery-jvectormap-2.0.2.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="world-map-markers" style="width: 720px; height: 400px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice but how i can use for different port ? how i can detect different port in js ? pleas can you make an example for my question?

Comment: thats a longer subject ... 1st you got to access the file content ... you can do that client side with a `<input type="file">` or serve it and use XMLHTTPRequest from the client ... 2nd with the file's content as a string you can use JSON to parse it as an object ... 3rd then you can use a few `if`s or a `switch .. case` to properly populate an array that you can store in a variable and then use as the marker's array.

Answer (score 0):

I think to set the initial marker style you would need to go through all the data and build a scale (grouping), which is then used by jvectormap to get the values for the marker.

Your script to get json data looks good, so you are first showing the map and then put the markers over them. I think its a good approach, and your script is just only missing a simple function to prepare the markers style, if i'm not wrong here.

I changed slightly your data because all coordinates are pointing to the same location and the markers overlaps. It would be also useful if you explain if this is what you have to deal with.

This is a simple function to get the styles for the markers, it's just like a boring switch:

```
function getMarkerStyle(port) {
    var styles = {'1020': {fill: '#cc6600', stroke: '#222222',r: 2},
                  '5050': {fill: '#aaa',stroke: '#bbb',r: 2}};
    var unknown = {fill: '#F00',stroke: '#000',r: 2};
    return styles[port] || unknown;
}
```

This shall be inside your getJSON callback function, instead of *$.each* i'm using here a classic *for loop*:

```
for (var i = 0, l = logFile.relays.length; i < l; i++) {
    var port = logFile.relays[i].or_addresses[0].split(':')[1];
    var id = logFile.relays[i].or_addresses[0].split(':')[0];
    var coords = [logFile.relays[i].latitude, logFile.relays[i].longitude];
    var name = id;
    var style = getMarkerStyle(port);
    mapObj.addMarker(id, {latLng: coords, name: name, style: style}, null);
}
```

You just only need to put the style inside the second parameter of the function addMarker.

Tested with jvectormap-2.0.2